# How do I get the text inside of a div which also has another element?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<p id="mydiv">
<img alt="Assets Received" src="/images/icons/statuses/generic.png" title="" height="16" width="16"> I want to get this text only, not the image element before me
</p>
```

I want to retrieve the text inside of mydiv excluding the image tag.
fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Town/5L3rd/

Comment: If you, like in this case, always have the text being the last node you could always use;

`alert(document.getElementById('mydiv').lastChild);`

Works on IE 6 and up.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers this property is called `textContent`:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').textContent // " I want to get this text only, not the image element before me"
```

If you want to support rocks and dust (IE8), you also need to check the `innerText` property. Together you can create a function to anonymously get the text:

```
function getText(el){
    return el.textContent || el.innerText;
}
```

Comment: does this work in IE8?

Comment: innerText does not work, it gives undefined

Comment: @DinǝshGupta Look at my newer edit. `innerText` is unsupported in modern browsers; therefore you need the check to either return `textContent`, and if not defined, the `innerText`.

Comment: On a compliant browser, `el.innerText` will be `undefined` and `el.textContent` might be `""`. But `"" || undefined` is `undefined`. Using `el.textContent || el.innerText || ''` may be better.

Comment: @Eric check my edit.. added a fiddle link